# Get bounds of the screen in SKScene - didMoveToView(...)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit and Swift, I have the following question:

I start a new SpriteKit Swift project and then open the

```
class GameScene: SKScene
```

there is the method

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
```

Now I want to create a worldBorder which is exactly the same size like the iphone screen (landscape or portrait)
It should be like the bounds within e.g. a ball can not get out.

I did something like this:

```
let worldBorder = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsBody = worldBorder
```

But this is not working, its bigger then the part which is dieplayed on the phone.

How to make this?

EDIT:
My GameScene has this properties and the heigh of my iphone work as a border. but in portraite mode the bounds are to much left and right.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that due to the fact worldBorder is a PhysicsBody, it is being affected by gravity and falling down past the screen. Try pinning it:

```
worldBorder.physicsBody?.pinned = true
```

Another option is to just create several nodes and position them at the border surrounding the frame.

Comment: Edge loop physics bodies are static

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let worldBorder = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame)
    self.physicsBody = worldBorder
}
```

I think maybe the `self.frame` hasn't been resized when `didMoveToView` is called. Also, if you support multiple orientations like portrait and landscape you might need to handle transitioning to the other size.